# Getting Error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, cors

I have enabled CORS using following:

```
private readonly string CorsPolicy = "CorsPolicy";

services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(this.CorsPolicy, builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins(this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("WebAppBaseUrl"))
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
               .AllowCredentials();
    });
});
```

appsettings.json entry:

```
"WebAppBaseUrl": "https://localhost:44372/"
```

But only for one GET request I'm getting the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44343/api/pushNotification/GetMyPushNotifications/1/1' from origin 'https://localhost:44372' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS PROJECT HAS MORE THAN 50 GET REQUESTS AND ALL OF THEM WORK FINE WITH CURRENT CORS CONFIGURATION, ONLY THIS SPECIFIC GET REQUEST GIVES ME THIS CORS ERROR.**

Any ideas?

Comment: Please note that CORS is already enabled. All the other requests are doing good. Only one is giving me  this issue.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After few days of trying I figured out the issue.

The API endpoint I was calling from was having 2 endpoints as below:

- `/getPushNotification/{userId}/{pageId}`
- `/getPushNotification/{userId}`

I tried same by changing them as below:

- `/getPagedPushNotification/{userId}/{pageId}`
- `/getPushNotification/{userId}`

It works fine now. Thanks for all who tried to help.

Answer (score 2):

In appsettings.json add section of AllowedOrigins like below

```
"AllowedOrigins": {
"WebAppBaseUrl": "https://localhost:44372/" }
```

Then in startup inject configuration to get list of allowed origin as below

```
string[] lstAllowedOrigins;
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        lstAllowedOrigins = Configuration.GetSection("AllowedOrigins").Get<string[]>();
    }
```

Finally add below middleware in Configure function as below

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
        {
            builder
            .WithOrigins(lstAllowedOrigins)
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials();
        });
```

Comment: This is already done using another way as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Oshadha did you try my answer? please share with me your result after applying this because it's working with me

Comment: I'm not using through services, i used middleware directly in Configure method

Comment: is there any api working with you or all calls failed for the above error ?

Comment: I have 20+ API endpoints. All of them work but this.

Comment: Could you please check windows event log, it happened sometimes if there is some unhandled exception in this method, you can find this error in windows event log viewer

Comment: I checked... No issues there.

Comment: Are you using this with Signal R ?

Comment: No.. No SignalR

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft documentation says that the specified URL must not contain a trailing slash (/). If the URL terminates with /, the comparison returns false and no header is returned. Change your appsettings:

```
"WebAppBaseUrl": "https://localhost:44372/"
```

to

```
"WebAppBaseUrl": "https://localhost:44372"
```

Comment: Sure I will do so. But, do you know why it works for al but this specific. Any idea why it happens like that.